# Power Query - DataSource.Error: An unknown error occurred when navigating to the web page

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using power query in excel and I can not scrape a page that has a table. It keeps telling me that the first step has an error. Is there something here I should change?

```
= Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/dynamicapp/QueryDaily?s=DMV&end=today&span=380days"))
```

The error is:

> DataSource.Error: An unknown error occurred when navigating to the web page.
> Details:

> DataSourceKind=Web
> DataSourcePath=http://cdec.water.ca.gov/dynamicapp/QueryDaily
> StatusCode=-2146697208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in Advanced Editor -

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/dynamicapp/QueryDaily?s=DMV&end=today&span=380days", [Timeout=#duration(0, 0, 2, 0), Headers=[#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip", #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", #"Accept-Language"="en-US", #"Content-Type"="text/html;charset=UTF-8"]]))
in
    Source
```

You're getting errors because the website isn't allowing "Excel-like" scrappers. You need to bypass it by masquerading like a browser.

By going to Advanced Option and filling in the referer details shown in the dropdown -
[image]

To get the corresponding info you need to go to inspect mode in Browser > Select Network Tab > Select the Network component

Look for the request header -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with no other tricks to it

```
let Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/dynamicapp/QueryDaily?s=DMV&end=today&span=380days")),
Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"DATE / TIME  (PST)", type date}, {"RES ELE FEET", type text}, {"", type text}, {"STORAGE AF", type text}, {"2", type text}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]